# Why doesn't string comparison with wildcards work properly?

Tags: linux, shell, if-statement

I wrote this shell code, but it doesn't get the good output.
Even though the $csoport gets the "...: No such user" output, id doesn't echoes the following line I wrote there.

```
 read felhasznalo
 while [ "$felhasznalo" != "exit" ]
 do
    csoport=`groups $felhasznalo`
    echo "$csoport"

    if [[ "$csoport" == *": No such user"* ]] ; then
            echo -n "Nincs ilyen felhasznalo a rendszerben"

    else
            echo "$csoport"
    fi
    echo -n "Felhasznalo: "
    read felhasznalo
 done
```

Comment: Remove quotation from "$csoport". Write $csoport.

Comment: @tomerpacific That's almost always bad advice for shell scripts. Always quote your variables.

Comment: The quotes aren't necessary, but they aren't a problem, either, in this case.

Comment: `[[` is really the only place in which it's appropriate to not quote variables, which in my book is an argument in favor of avoiding `[[`

Comment: @WilliamPursell There are others (e.g., `case $foo in ...`), and there are other, better, reasons to use `[[` than "I don't have to quote (some) parameter expansions."

Comment: I go back and forth on whether it's appropriate to leave variables unquoted on the RHS of assignments or in `case` statements, etc. The quotes are unnecessary there, but stylistically, I think quoting them is appropriate.  OTOH, leaving them unquoted in such places *may* contribute to a better understanding of quoting rules.  But that feels like a weak argument.  I've yet to see a convincing argument that `[[` is ever a good idea, though.

Comment: Pattern matching and regular expression matching are useful, but I have no problem with using `[` when it will do. Being able to write `[[ foo && bar ]]` instead of `[ foo ] && [ bar ]` is nice, but not critical (although inside `[[`, `&&` and `||` are actual logical operators with the expected precedence, unlike the shell list operators `&&` and `||`).

Comment: In any case, the reason why this is not working is that it doesn't capture the error on stderr. You could do ``csoport=`groups $felhasznalo 2>&1` `` but the suggested answer is better

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to match the error messsage since you only care if `groups` fails. You ought to do:

```
if ! csoport=$(groups "$felhasznalo"); then
        printf "Nincs ilyen felhasznalo a rendszerben"
else
        echo "$csoport"
fi
```

Comment: You probably want to redirect the error message to `/dev/null` as well, since it looks like a custom error message is being printed anyway.